# How to relate the asp webforms three tier structure with asp MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I am pretty new to ASP MVC. All the coding I have done to this day is based upon the three tier structure in `ASP Webforms`. However, I have been able to relate the `MVC project` structure with that of the ASP Webforms project structure. Like, I can pretty well understand how the controller and the views work, but there is a problem regarding the models.

My first question would be, is it necessary that we must follow the `Entity Framework` data model in `MVC`. I am pretty used to in `ADO.NET` and have been unable to understand how the entity framework works. Likewise, can we use the same three tier project structure in `ASP MVC4` for importing data from database completely neglecting the "MODEL".

Please, have your say in this. It is really getting confusing trying to implement the same three tier structure in MVC Projects.

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is an extensive topic, and i would like you to point you to a very nice tutorial that i am currently learning from !

[Getting Started with Entity Framework 4.0 Database First and ASP.NET 4 Web Forms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any pattern you like. MVC doesn't impose any restriction and it is not necessary to use Entity Framework or other ORM so if you are good at ADO you can use ADO.

There are various MVC open source project available on codeplex, you can refer those projects.

Tutorial and Project links:-

[Getting Started with EF using MVC](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

[Building an ASP.NET MVC4 Application with EF and Web API](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-an-asp-net-mvc4-application-with-ef-and-webapi/)

[Prodinner MVC Project](http://prodinner.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned MVC does not impose usage of any ORM. It is upon you how you build your models and supply data to it.

As with any new thing take some time to learn it before embarking upon a serious project.

Check out the [official MVC site](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials) for examples or [Pluralsight for tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/pluralsight) to get a deeper understanding of what ASP.NET MVC entails.

For EF, check out this [site](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/)

ORM like EF is used by many because it makes our tasks easier.

Although using Microsoft ASP.NET MVC technology without models is certainly possible , you will lose out on some of the MVC features like [Validation through Data Annotations](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/4/model_validation_in_asp_net_mvc) etc.(But then it would not really be MVC, is it?)

At my work place,we still use the three tier architecture. One contains all models,another our business logic and the last our views.We still use ADO.NET for bulk uploads and inserts as we found it is quite time consuming through an ORM.

So mix and match and march on!

Comment: Thanks for such a nice reply. It is really helpful to get suggestions midst these confusions. After some research, I have also developed an idea to work on MVC projects. I have created a class library replicating all the models that are to be used. Although the validation through data annotations cannot be used, but i have been doing validation through exception handling. Is it good to use such approach. Thanks again for replying!!!